# Rails query the last of each type

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I am using STI and have a table Widget that a bunch of other subclasses inherit from using STI.  I want a query that gets the last created of each object with a uniq type.

I have a predefined array of types I want so lets say:

```
types = ["type1", "type2", "type3"]
```

So my query would be something like: (this doesnt work)

```
Widget.where(type: types).uniq.reverse
```

My goal is to get the last of each object that matches 1 of those types..

Comment: By last did you mean the last record that was created for a particular type ?

Comment: yes the last record that was created per type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure, but something like this might work (untested):

```
ids = Thing.where(type: types).group(:type).maximum(:id).values
last_per_type = Thing.find(ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Thing.select("distinct type")
```

By the way, `type` is a special variable in rails and can't be used as a column name.

Comment: this doesnt seem to return the last created object, its returning <UiConfigStandWidget id: nil, type: "UiConfigStandWidget" instead of the actual record created in the db